# When is it a bad idea to use a heap for a Priority Queue?

Tags: algorithm, heap, priority-queue

In the section that explains Dijkstra's Algorithm in the book Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et. al., while analysing the complexity of the algorithm, they say

***If the graph is sufficiently sparse ... we can improve the algorithm by implementing the min priority queue with a binary min heap***

So I was wondering, what is the need for such a statement? Isn't it always wiser to just use heaps for priority queues?

Comment: What priority queue implementations do they mention/suggest apart from binary heaps?

Comment: +1 I have a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219691/advantages-of-a-binary-heap-for-a-priority-queue

Answer (score 3):

There are many different ways to implement a priority queue. A binary min heap is useful because it performs reasonably well and is easy to implement. But a [pairing heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap) is pretty easy to implement, too, and it has better performance for some operations. In particular, it does a *decrease key* operation much more quickly than a binary heap does.

Or you could go with a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) priority queue. A skip list has some nice properties that make it attractive in some priority queue applications. In particular, it's easier to make a concurrent skip list than a concurrent heap.

So, no, it's not always wiser to use heaps for priority queues. It's almost certainly wiser to use a heap than a sorted list, but there are times when something else is more appropriate than a heap.

Answer (score 1):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

It says:

> - Dijkstra's original algorithm does not use a min-priority queue and runs in O(|V|^2).

So the statement in the book is just saying that the original algorithm can be optimized.

> - The implementation based on a min-priority queue implemented by a **Fibonacci heap** and running in O(|E|+|V|log|V|) (where |E| is the number of edges) is due to (Fredman & Tarjan 1984).

Binary heap is only one type of heap. There are other types which fit specific scenes better.